# Como utilizar Segmented Controls no Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.ios

Galera,

Uma ajuda,

Preciso utilizar um tipo de Segmented Controls no meu Xamarin Forms. Porem não existe. Eu vi que da para utilizar Nativo por plataforma, mas nao achei nenhum exemplo ou documentação guia para isso.

Alguém ja fez algo parecido ?

Obs: vi algumas gambetas no GITHUB, queria saber se da pra fazer com nativeview mesmo, para nao quebrar os Guidelines.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar  o package https://www.nuget.org/packages/SegmentedControl.FormsPlugin/ ?

Comment: Tentei, acabei resolvendo de outra forma. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera,

Acabei resolvendo com o FreshEssentials. ( https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreshEssentials/) . Ele instala controles para o xamarin forms que ainda não foram implementados pela Microsoft.